# Copy and Update a property of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, redux, spread-syntax

For my app using redux I have an array and I want to update some properties of one object. Because it's redux I need a copy of the array, therefore I want to use the spread operator.

Input:

```
const original = [{a: "original a", b: "original b"}, {c: "original c", d: "original d"}];
```

What I tried:

```
const output = [...o1, Object.assign({}, o1[0], { a: "new value" })];
console.log(o2);
```

Instead of updating the first object in the array this appends a new object to the array.

```
//what I want to be the output
[{ a: "updated a", b: "updated b" },{ c: "original c", d: "original d" } ]
```

Comment: how you want the update to be happen ?

Comment: May I know your expected output?

Comment: sorry I added the desired output now :)

Comment: you are spreading an array into an object

Comment: I am a bit concerned about your output. Should it be an object or an array?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. it should be an array containing those two objects

Comment: The input and output are still ambiguous to me. Are `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` real keys or you have just provided them as a placeholder for the question. It would be better if you can post the actual array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to spread array into an object and adding additional keys for which the output that is coming is correct. If you want the desired output you will have to make the keys same before using spread operator that is if you want override keys of the object at the 0th position you will have to merge to it to an array of the object whose element at 0th position overrides your keys.

```
const o1 = [
  { a: "original a", b: "original b" },
  { c: "original c", d: "original d" }
];

const updatedObj = [
  {
    a: "updated a",
    b: "updated b"
  }
];
const mergeObj = { ...o1, ...updatedObj };
const o2 = Object.values(mergeObj);
console.log(o2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

`Object.assign` is used to replace some proprieties of an object:

```
// example object
let obj = { a: "original", b: "original" };

// use object.assign to create a new updated object 
// maybe you want to update `a` property
let updated_obj = Object.assign({}, obj, { a: "new value });

console.log(updated_obj); //{ a: "new value", b: "original" }
```

Answer (score 1):

using Shubham Gupta idea, instead of destructuring I went for object assign and seems to work

```
const o1 = [
  { a: "original a", b: "original b" },
  { c: "original c", d: "original d" }
];

const updatedObj = [
  { a: "updated a",
    b: "updated b"
  }
];

const o2 = Object.assign(o1,updatedObj);
console.log(o2);
```

the example code is over here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPGgGm?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Input and Output are still concerned for me. You should remember that an object cannot have duplicate key, However an array can have same element multiple times. Based on your required output, the input and solution could be in this way.

```
const o1 = {a: "original a", b: "original b"};
const o2 = {c: "original c", d: "original d"};
const o3 = {a: "updated a", b: "updated b"};

o4 = {...o1, ...o2, ...o3};
console.log(o4);
```